# Returned textbox value is empty

Tags: c#

Sorry I'm still learning C#, but here's my code and I need help. Basically here's how it is:

The first part of my code went to a settings window where the textbox displays "0%" and my code enters a value of 10 to it.

```
public void SetDefaultAmount(int amt)
{
 Settings.EnterAmt(amt);
}

public void EnterAmt(int amt)
{
 string amount = amt.ToString();
 Settings.TextBox.Text = amt;
}
```

So now in setting window, the textbox displays "10%".

My next code goes to a User window where it displays the same textbox and the default value, so the textbox displays "10%" correctly.

I need a code that grabs the textbox value in the Users page, and compare it with the value from the settings page to check if they match. But when i run my code, it gives me the error of "Expected: 10, But was: "string.Empty". How can I fix this? And any better way of streamlining my code? thanks!

This is what my 2nd code is currently, that fails:

**Check if value is 10 (amt = 10)

```
public void CheckValue(int amt)
{
 string amount = amt.ToString();
 string actualval = UserPage.GetActualVal();
 Assert.AreEqual(amount, actualval, "value did not match");
}

public string GetActualVal()
{
 return UserPage.Textbox.Text;
}
```

Comment: I'm reading that you have 2 separate windows: Users and Settings. Both have a textbox named Textbox1. These are 2 completely separate and unrelated textboxes. Putting a value in the Settings page textbox will do nothing for the Users page textbox - that's why GetActualVal() gives you string.Empty

Comment: I updated my example code above. I checked my actual code and the textbox name are different since theyre form different windows as well.

Comment: Your error is telling you that UserPage.Textbox.Text is empty. i.e. there is no text there. Have you actually typed anything into the UserPage Textbox? From the code you have provided, I am assuming that UserPage is the name of the window and you have a textbox named "Textbox" ?

Comment: After another hour of checking my code, it actually works. the problem turned out to be the automation id of the textbox in the Users page, which was changed without my knowledge so i corrected it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another hour of checking my code, it actually works. the problem turned out to be the automation id of the textbox in the Users page, which was changed without my knowledge so i corrected it already. Thanks for checking and i'd just probably try streamline my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing amt, an integer, to actualval, a string.  Try Assert.AreEqual(amount, actualval).

Comment: i see what you mean, i edited my assert line, but my problem still persist with the empty string result...

Comment: Here's another question.  Why are you calling UserPage.GetActualVal() which calls UserPage.Textbox.Text.  The second one is already in UserPage, so you should be able to call Textbox.Text.  Something doesn't add up here.  Is UserPage the settings window?  Or the main window?